# Calculating values of a column and writing them to an excel file

Tags: excel, matlab

I have an excel file with some column data. The second column contains time values in the following format: HH:MM:SS. I would like to calculate some new values, based on the values from column A, and write them to another, empty column.

Example of the excel sheet layout:

```
A           B        C         D   
12:30:00    xxx      xxx       calculated value
00:30:00    xxx      xxx       calculated value
```

The values in column D would be calculated in this way (pseudo code):

```
for every value in column A:
   val temp = convert value in column A to minutes and divide by 30 
   (e.g. 00:30 --> (0 * 60) + 30 = 30/30 = 1)

   if (temp < 24):
      cellDValue = -180 + (temp * 7,5)
   else
      temp = temp - 24
      cellDValue = temp * 7,5
```

So the above sheet would look like this:

```
A           B        C         D   
12:30:00    xxx      xxx       7,5
00:30:00    xxx      xxx       -127,5
```

What would be the fastest way to achieve this?

Comment: why did you tag this Maltab? You can do that pretty easily without leaving Excel...

Comment: Because it has to be a scipt in matlab, which would be more readable -    easier for me to explain the program logic.

Comment: But this is really easy to do in a single Excel formula - or alternatively you could put each operation in a different column if you want to illustrate the logic. I mean, it's easy in Maltab too but it's seriously over-complicating matters. But also if you want Matlab code, then lets first see your attempt at it.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a go. But I already have a problem. Matlab converts the dates into serial date number (12:30 -->0.5208). Are there any built in methods which retun hours and minutes from that format?

Comment: [`datevec`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datevec.html) but you'll probably also need `x2mdate` and `m2xdate`

Comment: @RunoTheDog, as I see your `If` and `else` parts are the same: we could rewrite `else` part as `cellDValue = (temp - 24) * 7,5 = temp * 7,5 - 24*7.5 = temp * 7,5 - 180` whitch is equal to `If` part

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve the values from the dates with this code:

dim intSecond as integer
    dim intMin as integer
    dim intHour as integer
    dim intDay as integer
    dim intMonth as integer
    dim intYear as integer

```
dim objDate as date 
objDate = now

intSecond = Second(objDate)
intMin=  Minute(objDate)
intHour = Hour(objDate)
intDay = Day(objDate)
intMonth = Month(objDate)
intYear = Year(objDate)
```

Copy them to another cell and to the calculations you need.